# Ansible dynamic variable

Tags: dynamic, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a file that looks like this:

```
message1,abcde,loc
message2,kkjojao,ethd
message3,abcde,eth4
```

I want to filter the file to create a lists that should look like this (similar value at the second position):

```
message1,abcde,loc
message3,abcde,eth4
```

and then send the messages using a task.

How can I do it with Ansible?

Comment: What is the logic for filtering out `message2`? Imagine there is a `message4` with `kkjojao`, what should Ansible do with it? What do you mean by _send the messages_? What have you tried so far? Please read [ask].

Comment: message 4 with kkjojao should be treated the same way as message 2 because they are duplicates

Answer (score 0):

There is a csvfile lookup that you can use for the input, and plenty jinja2 filters.

Comment: Lookups only work on the files on the controller and you have no indication from the OP question that this is their case.

Comment: fetch the file and it's on the controller.